# NHibernate MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document

Tags: nhibernate, exception, deployment, nhibernate-mapping

On my dev web app NHibernate is working just dandy. When I precompile and deploy the site, I get a MappingException when the SessionFactory is created.

Here's some info from the trace:

> NHibernate.Cfg.Environment    2010-07-15 09:20:59,577 [7] INFO 
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Environment [(null)] - NHibernate 2.1.2.4000
>   (2.1.2.4000)
>     0.452436832055471   0.232383 NHibernate.Cfg.Environment 2010-07-15 09:20:59,718 [7] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment [(null)] - Bytecode
>   provider name : lcg
>     0.522780409241957   0.070344 NHibernate.Cfg.Environment 2010-07-15 09:20:59,734 [7] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment [(null)] - Using
>   reflection optimizer
>     0.529107470362853   0.006327 NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration   2010-07-15 09:20:59,827 [7] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration [(null)] - Mapping
>   resource: Kctc.BusinessLayer.Mappings.StoredWill.hbm.xml
>     0.623336485503046   0.094229 NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect 2010-07-15 09:21:00,109 [7] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect [(null)] - Using
>   dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
>     0.91570185596214    0.292365 NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration   2010-07-15 09:21:01,390 [7] ERROR NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration [(null)] - Could
>   not compile the mapping document:
>   Kctc.BusinessLayer.Mappings.StoredWill.hbm.xml
>   NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document:
>   Kctc.BusinessLayer.Mappings.StoredWill.hbm.xml --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class
>   (result=1). error CS2001: Source file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\shp2uoc8.0.cs'
>   could not be found error CS2008: No inputs specified
>
> at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String
>   ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence) 
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly,
>   Hashtable assemblies)   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings,
>   Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence
>   evidence)   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping
>   xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String
>   defaultNamespace)   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder.Deserialize[T](XmlNode node)   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.MappingRootBinder.Bind(XmlNode node)   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument
>   doc)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     2.20609881982207    1.290397 Unhandled Execution Error   Could not compile the mapping document:
>   Kctc.BusinessLayer.Mappings.StoredWill.hbm.xml   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument
>   doc)   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDocumentThroughQueue(NamedXmlDocument
>   document)   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReader
>   hbmReader, String name)   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream,
>   String name)   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String
>   path, Assembly assembly)   at
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)   at
>   Kctc.BusinessLayer.NHibernateSessionFactory.get_SessionFactory() in
>   C:\Kctc\Trunk\Kctc.BusinessLayer\NHibernateSessionFactory.cs:line 26
>   at Kctc.BusinessLayer.NHibernateSessionFactory.OpenSession() in
>   C:\Kctc\Trunk\Kctc.BusinessLayer\NHibernateSessionFactory.cs:line 39
>   at Developers_Test.ListSquirps(Object sender, EventArgs e)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)   at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 2.20665643259129    0.000558

This suggests to me either that the mapping file has an error or could not be found. But if the dev app works fine, how can there be an issue with the mapping file when it is precompiled and deployed?!

Does anyone have any suggestion as to what might be happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Here's another thought. Since NHibernate generates proxy classes, do these get stored on the file system? Is it possible this is a file permissions issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I've got it.  The XmlSerializer class which is invoked during the creation of the SessionFactory needs write access to (by default) C:\Windows\TEMP so that it can generate some stuff and whack it in there.

Alternatively, you can follow the hack on this blog http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingWhereXmlSerializerOutputsTemporaryAssemblies.aspx. This changes the default location that XmlSerializer stores its shiznit. All you have to do is add the following element within the configuration element of your web.config / app.config file:

```
<system.xml.serialization>
  <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="C:\SomeFolder\SomeOtherFolder\WhereeverYouWant"/>
</system.xml.serialization>
```

The first solution feels like a security issue, and the second one feels like a clumsy hack with hard-to-foresee consequences.

Why is this so poorly documented?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments under gillyb's answer, I actually solved this problem by using FluentNHibernate instead - then there is no need for XML files at all.

Comment: + thank you thank you thank you, I've literally spent half a day on this... I thought it was a windsor lifestyle issue, a db issue... geez, thank you! (weirdly this problem still occurs with fluent?? that's what i'm using and had the same issue, and this fixed it)

Comment: Are you using Fluent for ALL configuration (e.g. including driver information, database platform etc) or just the mapping configuration? Put another way, do you have ANY XML associated with configuring NHibernate?

Comment: Also, just to say Andy, I've really enjoyed reading some of your questions. There should be an option to 'follow' other users.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the .hbm.xml file is defined as an embedded resource in your project.

Comment: It is, but thanks for the suggestion. I assume the Copy To Output property is irrelevant for an embedded resource?

Comment: So take another suggestion - Start using FluentNHibernate, it's so much easier and more comfortable to create Table Mappings with! :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, gillyb! I have heard of FluentNHibernate, but just want to get to grips with plain vanilla mapping first. It does look quite cool though.

Comment: Hey, that would mean no XML files, no XmlSerializer class, and no need to deal with the file permissions issue. That could be really useful - thanks again.

Comment: Yep! It's so much more comfortable using FluentNHibernate, and much more fluent (obviously!). A friend of mine started out with it, and thanked a lot afterwards. :)

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the FluentNHibernate tip. Just got it working, and it's great!